# Symfony - Trabalhar com imagens?

Tags: php, imagem, symfony-2, symfony

Galera  preciso criar imagem com php , eu gostaria de saber se o Simfony tem alguma biblioteca ou algo já incluído nele pra trabalhar com as funções GD/ImageMagick. Eu estive pesquisando e vi "LiipImagineBundle", mas ele me parece bem limitado , por exemplo não sei se consigo criar uma imagem  com essa biblioteca. Alguém sabe sobre alguma biblioteca ou até mesmo sobre esse  LiipImagineBundle? Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Para o tratamento de imagens existem diversas bibliotecas disponíveis.
O [LiipImagineBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/liip/imagine-bundle) tem como propósito geral facilitar a tarefa de servir imagens. No seu caso, para a criação de imagens, acredito que ele não irá servir.

Fiz uma busca rápida e encontrei a [phpixie/image](https://packagist.org/packages/phpixie/image) que me pareceu ser bem simples e funcional.
A biblioteca [Gregwar/image](https://packagist.org/packages/gregwar/image) também me parece uma ótima opção.

Não utilizei nenhuma delas, portanto minha avaliação é limitada a API e a documentação disponível.

Caso você queira pesquisar mais bibliotecas, o site do [packagist](https://packagist.org) possui várias opções.

Answer (score 0):

você não necessáriamente precisa utilizar os bundles do Symfony. No Symfony é possível instalar componentes via composer e basta utilizar a Classe no seu Controller.

Componentes de manipulação de imagens de terceiros:
[Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)
[Imanee](http://imanee.io/)

Você instala com o composer:

```
composer require imanee/imanee
```

E Utiliza dentro do método no Controller:

```
$imanee = new \Imanee('test.jpg');
echo $imanee->thumbnail(200, 200, true)
    ->output();
```

OBS: Para instanciar Classes no Symfony é necessário utilizar "\".